# Find the point equidistant from two points and a line

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given a line $l$ and two points $p_1$ and $p_2$, identify the point $v$ which is equidistant from $l$, $p_1$, and $p_2$, assuming it exists.

My idea is to: (1) identify the parabolas containing all points equidistant from each point and the line, then (2) intersect these parabolas. As $v$ is equidistant from all three and each parabola contains all points equidistant from $l$ and each point, the intersection of these parabolas must be $v$. However, I have had no luck in finding a way to compute, much less represent, these parabolas.

Comment: The question does not mention a coordinate system. All answers so far assume that if you have coordinates, you transform them into a coordinate system that is convenient, solve for $v$ in that system, and then transform back (if you want the answer in the original coordinate system).

Comment: I think [Yves' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2555611/415941) is very compact and says everything you need to know. You cannot do better than solving this quadratic equation. And it should hopefully be no problem to rotate/translate your line into place to match the $x$-axis. If this (or any other) answer does not fit your needs I guess you have to modify your question in order to make clear what would be an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming such point $Q$ exists it must lie on the **Bisector Line b** of $P_1$ and $P_2$ i.e. the line through the midpoint of $P_1$ and $P_2$ and orthogonal to the line $\vec {P_1P_2}$.

[image]

Thus you can write down a parametric expression for $Q=Q(s)\in b$ and set the following **equation for distances**:

> $$d^2(Ql)=d^2(QP_1)$$

Firstly note that, without loss of generality, we can **assume that the origin** coincides with the intersection point between $l$ and $b$. In fact if $b\equiv l$ solution is trivial otherwise if not we can find the intersection point and simply shift the axes (we could also rotate the axes in such way that $l$ or $b$ coincide with an axis but it should be more complex whereas shifting is trivial).

Thus, let's assume:

$P_1=(x_1,y_1), P_2=(x_2,y_2)$,

**l:** $ ax+by=0$,

**b:** $cx+dy=0$

**NOTE**

find c and d is trivial

[Finding perpendicular bisector of the line segement joining $ (-1,4)\;\text{and}\;(3,-2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442781/finding-perpendicular-bisector-of-the-line-segement-joining-1-4-textand)

Parametric equation of $Q \in b$ is given by:

$Q(t)=Q(d \cdot t,-c \cdot t)$ with $t\in \mathbb{R}$

The distances are given by:

$$\text{d($Ql$)} = \frac{\left | Ax_{0} + By_{0} + C\right |}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2} }= \frac {\left| ad\cdot t - bc\cdot t \right|}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} $$

$$\text{d($QP_1$)} = \sqrt{(d\cdot t-x_1)^2 + (-c\cdot t-y_1)^2}$$

and thus

$$\frac {\left| adt - bct \right|}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}=\sqrt{(d\cdot t-x_1)^2 + (-c\cdot t-y_1)^2}$$

$$\frac {\left( ad\cdot t - bc\cdot t \right)^2}{{a^2 + b^2}}=(d\cdot t-x_1)^2 + (-c\cdot t-y_1)^2$$

from which "t" and thus "Q" can be easily found.

Comment: The points we want are on $b$, but not on $\ell$.

Comment: Correct. The intersection of $b$ with $l$ will be equidistant from $p_1$ and $p_2$ but not from $l$ itself.

Comment: Sorry of course! I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: I've updated the hint!

Comment: Now it should be ok! I hope!

Comment: A very good hint!

Comment: I am having quite a hard time working out the algebra on this one. It is easy enough to write out the equations using determinants and vectors, but I am unable to tease out of that an equation for the center of the "circumcircle". Any further help here would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have specific data for the problem or you want solve it in general?

Comment: I would like to solve it in general. Any two points and any line. Well, assuming the two points are not on the line.

Comment: @CoderTheTyler I've added the full solution following the hint.

Comment: Thanks! I can see at least one issue though; you seem to use $x_1$ and $x_2$ instead of $x_1$ and $y_1$?

Comment: oh yes my fault! I update, are you ok now with the solution?

Comment: @CoderTheTyler Are you ok now with the solution?

Comment: All of the answers given were each great, but this solution was the most, for lack of a better word, complete. The construction is simple, and the need to only translate the final result by the intersection point makes it quite user-friendly (as opposed to rotating the final point because of the assumption of one of the lines being an axis). Thanks!

Comment: @CoderTheTyler Thanks I'm happy that you have found thi solution useful. Bye.

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality, $l$ is the $x$ axis, $p_1$ is at $(-a,y_1)$ and $p_2$ at $(a,y_2)$.

One of the parabolas is $$y^2=(x+a)^2+(y-y_1)^2$$ and the other

$$y^2=(x-a)^2+(y-y_2)^2.$$

After elimination of $y$,

$$y_2(x+a)^2-y_1(x-a)^2+y_1y_2(y_1-y_2)=0$$ can give you two solutions.

Answer (score 2):

An approach that could be useful not only to provide the solutions, but also to discuss and understand their existence, is as follows. Given two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ and a line, we can set, without loss of generality,  an $xy$ plane where the $x$-axis coincides with the line and the non-negative portion of the $y$-axis contains  $P_1$. The coordinates of $P_1$ and $P_2$ can then be written as $(0,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, respectively  (with $y_1 \geq 0\,$).    The segment $P_1P_2$ has slope $(y_2-y_1)/x_2$ and its middle point has coordinates $(x_2/2,(y_1+y_2)/2)\,\,\,\,$. So the equation of its geometric axis is

$$y=-\frac{x_2}{y_2-y_1} x + \frac{y_1+y_2}{2}+\frac{x_2^2}{2(y_2-y_1)} $$

Now we have to identify, on this line, a point whose distance from $P_1$ (or $P_2$) is equal to the distance from the $x$-axis. Therefore, if we call $(X,Y)$ the coordinates of this point, we must have

$$X^2+(Y-y_1)^2=Y^2$$

Since $(X,Y)$ must also satisfy the equation of the geometric axis, solving the system and simplifying we get that the searched coordinates are

$$X=\frac{y_1 x_2}{y_1 - y_2} \pm \sqrt{y_1 y_2\left(1 + \frac{x_2^2}{(y_1 - y_2)^2} \right) }$$
$$ Y= \frac{y_1+y_2}{2} + \frac{x_2 (2X-x_2)}{2(y_1 - y_2)}$$

Note that these formulas are valid for $y_1 \neq y_2\,$. If $y_1=y_2\,$ (i.e., if the geometric axis is perpendicular to the $x$-axis), we trivially have

$$X=\frac{x_2}{2}$$
$$Y=\frac{y_1}{2}+\frac{X^2}{2y_1}$$

Also note that, for the solutions to be real, $y_1y_2$ must be $\geq 0\,\,$. Because $y_1$ has been assumed $ \geq 0$ in the initial assumptions ($P_1$ is on the non-negative portion of the $y$-axis) this implies that:

- in the case $y_1 \neq y_2 \,$, if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are both $>0$ (i.e.,  $P_1$ is on the positive $y$-axis and $P_2$ is in the first or second quadrant)  we have two different real solutions;
- in the case $y_1 \neq y_2\,$, if $y_1=0$ or $y_2=0$ (i.e.,  one among $P_1$ and $P_2$ is on the $x$-axis)  we have a single real solution;
- in the case $y_1 \neq y_2\,$, if $y_1>0$ and $y_2<0$ (i.e.,  $P_1$ is on the positive $y$-axis and $P_2$ is in the third or fourth quadrant)  we have no real solutions;
- lastly, in the case $y_1 = y_2\,$,  we have a single real solution.

---

To provide an example, let us set $P_1=(0,2) \,\,$ and $P_2=(2,4)\,\,$. In this case, we have $y_1=2\,$, $x_2=2\,\,$,$y_2=4\,\,$, and we are in the case $y_1 \neq y_2\,\,\,$. Applying the formulas above, we get

$$X=\frac{4}{-2} \pm \sqrt{2 \cdot 4 \left(1 + \frac{2^2}{(-2)^2} \right) }=-2 \pm 4$$

Putting these two possible values of $X$ in the equation giving $Y$, for the case $X=2\,\,$ yields

$$ Y= \frac{2+4}{2} + \frac{2 (4-2)}{2(-2)}= 3-1=2$$

and for the case $X=-6 \,\,$ yields

$$ Y= \frac{2+4}{2} + \frac{2 (2 \cdot (-6)-2)}{2(-2)}= 3+7=10$$

finally giving the two solutions $(2,2) \,$ and $(-6,10)\,$. Accordingly, the distances of $(2,2) \,$from $P_1$, $P_2$, and the $x$-axis are all equal to $2$, and those of $(-6,10)\,$ are all equal to $10$.

In the same manner, if for example we set $P_1=(0,4)\,\,$ and $P_2=(12,4)\,\,$, then $y_1=4\,$, $x_2=12\,\,\,$,$y_2=4\,\,$ and we are in the case $y_1 = y_2\,\,$, where the geometric axis is perpendicular to the $x$-axis. So we obtain

$$X=\frac{12}{2}=6$$
$$Y=\frac{4}{2}+\frac{6^2}{2 \cdot4}=\frac{13}{2}$$

giving the single solution $(6,13/2) \,\,$, whose distances from $P_1$, $P_2$, and the $x$-axis are all equal to $13/2 \,$.

Answer (score 2):

I  think you are almost there. The parabola has a property you already know.There are $two$ solutions/points for circle centers, but not one, get detected by a  direct procedure as follows:

Intersections of a *properly/conveniently  placed parabola* ( wlog $y=-f$ is chosen directrix) and perpendicular bisector of $P_1P_2 $ should be found.

$$ P_1:(a,b)\, ;  P_2: (0,f) ; $$ where $f$ is parabola focal length.

Bisector equation is

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2= x^2+(y-f)^2$$

Simplifying

$$ y(f-b)-ax+Q=0 ,\,where\,  Q=(a^2+b^2-f^2)/2 \tag 1 $$

Parabola equation

$$ y = \frac{x^2}{4f} \tag2 $$

Plug 2) into 1) and solve quadratic in $x$, getting two solutions, meaning two points satisfy the given condition.

The key point to realize is... there is a *single parabola*, not two, containing centers of these *two circles* on the parabola, but not one circle.

$$ x_1 = 2/ (1 - b/f)*(a + \sqrt{a^2 - Q (1 - b/f)}; \, y_1 = x_1^2/(4 f) ; $$

$$ x_2 = 2/ (1 - b/f)*(a - \sqrt{a^2 - Q (1 - b/f)}; \, y_2 = x_2^2/(4 f); $$

For the numerical example given in graph, I have taken the values $ (a,b,f)=((1,3,1)$ as numerical input.

and it results in coordinates of intersection points of circumcircle centers. By evaluation/calculation approximately they are :

$$C_1=(-4.16228,4.33114);\, C_2=(2.16228,1.16886) ; \,$$ which depicts two circumcircles as you desired.

EDIT1:

Another possibility for $l$ seems to exist as given schematically; however it is not an independent situation for the line given but reflection about line of centers.

[image: Parabola&Directrix MSE]
EDIT2:

If we take $(P_1,P_2)$ as $(-c,0),(c,0)$ and the given line as $ y= m x + c, $ the equations to the (tilted double parabola ) would be simplest.

Comment: This shows the geometry of the solution nicely. I would only add that technically there are two parabolas, but you only need to use one of them and find its intersections with the perpendicular bisector. The other parabola will necessarily intersect the perpendicular bisector at the same points, so it adds no information toward solving this problem.

Comment: There are two direct tangents. The OP has referred only to a single line $l$. So the other parabola/directrix $d_2, l_2$  combination excludes itself automatically. Of course a total picture would include a second directrix at some angle.

Comment: I thought the line $l$ was the directrix of each parabola mentioned by OP, and no matter which parabola you choose, you will get the same two circles tangent to $l.$ Of course if the two points are at different distances from $l,$ the choice of coordinate system is determined by which point we choose as a focus, and we want to work only with the parabola at that focus. My point was just that if we had chosen the other point as a focus we would have gotten the same two intersection points and circles--and that is why it is OK to choose the first focus and ignore the other.

Comment: Yes indeed, I was referring to a choice I made from the double solution. I  include a rough sketch to depict what I think you/we are both saying in wider context.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to attack such problems first using basic vector algebra, mostly because they tend to be easier to implement for numerical computations.

In other words, this answer assumes the underlying problem to be solved, is to find and implement a stable numerical algorithm for solving specific problems of this type; and not something like a geometric exercise or educational investigation.

---

First, we want to simplify the situation. The obvious operation is to transform the system so that the line $l$ is on the $x$ axis.

Let's define the line $l$ in vector form:
$$\vec{l}(t) = \vec{l}_0 + t \hat{l}_n \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
where $\vec{l}_0 = (x_0 ,\, y_0)$ is any point the line passes through, and $\hat{l}_n = (x_n ,\, y_n)$ is an unit vector ($x_n^2 + y_n^2 = 1$).

If we define rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$,
$$\mathbf{R} = \left [ \begin{array}{cc} x_n & y_n \\ y_n & -x_n \end{array} \right ] \tag{2}\label{NA2}$$
then the transformation we want is
$$\vec{p}' = \mathbf{R}\left(\vec{p} - \vec{l}_0\right)\tag{3a}\label{NA3a}$$
i.e. point $\vec{p} = (x, y)$ becomes
$$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}
x' = x_n ( x - x_0 ) + y_n ( y - y_0 ) \\
y' = y_n ( x - x_0 ) - x_n ( y - y_0 )
\end{array}\right.\tag{3b}\label{NA3b}$$

The inverse operation is $$\vec{p} = \vec{l}_0 + \mathbf{R}^T \vec{p}'$$
and because $\mathbf{R}^T = \mathbf{R}$ in this particular case, we can write it as
$$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}
x = x_0 + x_n x' + y_n y' \\
y = y_0 + y_n x' - x_n y' \end{array}\right.\tag{3c}\label{NA3c}$$

---

Next, we can consider this much simpler situation.

Let's say the two points (as transformed by $\eqref{NA3b}$) are $\vec{p}_1 = ( x_1 ,\, y_1 )$ and $\vec{p}_2 = ( x_2 ,\, y_2 )$.

The requirement for the point $\vec{p} = ( x ,\, y )$ we seek is that it is as far from $\vec{p}_1$ and $\vec{p}_2$ as it is from the line $l$, i.e. from $y = 0$.
$$\begin{cases}
\lvert y \rvert = \sqrt{ (x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2 } \\
\lvert y \rvert = \sqrt{ (x - x_2)^2 + (y - y_2)^2 } \end{cases}$$
Because both sides are nonnegative, we can square them, to get the pair of equations in a more tractable form,
$$\begin{cases}
y^2 = (x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2 \\
y^2 = (x - x_2)^2 + (y - y_2)^2 \end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}
(x - x_1)^2 + y_1^2 - 2 y y_1 = 0 \\
(x - x_2)^2 + y_2^2 - 2 y y_2 = 0 \end{cases} \tag{4}\label{NA4}$$
After finding the solution or solutions $(x, y)$, use $\eqref{NA3c}$ to transform them back to the original coordinate system.

---

Let's consider the numerical solutions to $\eqref{NA4}$, and the cases where there is no solution at all. (I shall quietly assume you are aware of the pitfalls when using floating-point numbers; especially allowing for rounding error, *"machine epsilon"*, when comparing values for equality.)

1. If $y_1 y_2 \lt 0$, there can be no result, because the given points are on different sides of the line: the distance from the tentative result point to at least one of the given points is always greater than the distance from the tentative result point to the line.
2. If $y_1 \ne y_2$, but $y_1 = 0$ or $y_2 = 0$ (or $y_1 y_2 = 0$), there can be no result, because only one of the given points is on the line $l$, and the common distance cannot be zero and nonzero at the same time.
3. If $y_1 = y_2 = 0$ but $x_1 \ne x_2$, there is no solution, because the given points are separate but both on the line $l$, and the common distance cannot be both zero and nonzero at the same time.
4. If $y_1 = y_2 = 0$ and $x_1 = x_2$, the given points are at the same point on the line $l$, so the common distance is zero. The result is the position of the given points:
   $$\begin{cases}x = x_1 = x_2 \\ y = y_1 = y_2 = 0 \end{cases}$$
5. If $y_1 = y_2 \ne 0$ and $x_1 = x_2$, the given points are the same, and the result is at midway between the given points and the line:
   $$\begin{cases}x = x_1 = x_2 \\ y = \frac{y_1}{2} = \frac{y_2}{2} \end{cases}$$
6. If $y_1 = y_2 \ne 0$ and $x_1 \ne x_2$, there is a single solution:
   $$\begin{cases}x = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} \\ y = \frac{y_1}{2} + \frac{(x_2 - x_1)^2}{8 y_1} \end{cases}$$
7. If $y_1 \ne y_2$, $y_1 y_2 \gt 0$, and $x_1 = x_2$, there given points are on the line perpendicular to line $l$, on the same side of line $l$, and there is a pair of solutions:
   $$\begin{cases}
      x = x_1 \pm \sqrt{y_1 y_2} \\
      y = \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2} \end{cases}$$
8. Otherwise, $y_1 \ne y_2$, $y_1 y_2 \gt 0$, and $x_1 \ne x_2$, and there are two solutions:
   $$\begin{cases}
      x = \frac{x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1 + \sqrt{y_1 y_2 \left ( (x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 \right )}}{y_2 - y_1} \\
      y = \frac{(y_1 + y_2) \left ( (x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 \right ) - (x_2 - x_1)\sqrt{y_1 y_2 \left ( (x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 \right )}}{(y_2 - y_1)^2 } \end{cases}$$
   and
   $$\begin{cases}
      x = \frac{x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1 - \sqrt{y_1 y_2 \left ( (x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 \right )}}{y_2 - y_1} \\
      y = \frac{(y_1 + y_2) \left ( (x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 \right ) + (x_2 - x_1)\sqrt{y_1 y_2 \left ( (x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 \right )}}{(y_2 - y_1)^2 } \end{cases}$$
   If you need to choose only one of the solutions, I recommend choosing the one with minimum $y$ in magnitude, $\lvert y \rvert$, as that solution corresponds to the smaller common distance.

If there is a solution, you can use $\eqref{NA3c}$ to convert back to the original coordinate system.

Note that the above cases are not in recommended implementation order; if you draw the cases into a diagram, you'll see you have a simple decision tree. As conditionals tend to be slow on current hardware, implementing a decision tree (to find the solution in fewest average and maximum conditional tests) is recommended.

Also note that I obtained the above solutions using free and open source Sagemath, but there may be transcription errors. If you find an error, or a suspicious point, please let me know in a comment so I can verify and fix.

Answer (score 1):

@anatoly has a nice answer which identifies conditions when a solution is expected. But there is an additional condition which, if not satisfied, prohibits a solution. @nominal-animal elucidates all conditions. I add an additional answer here only to show that using a different orientation of points and lines gives a compact solution for the point(s) which are equidistant to the line and the two points. It also lends itself well to constructing the solution

I prefer to let the the *unit measure* be the half distance between the two points and then imagine points on the x-axis at (-1,0) and (1,0) and the line having slope $m$ and y-intercept of $b$ (hence, x-intercept of $b/m$).

Using SymPy to work out the location of the point $(x,y)$ that is equidistant from the line and the points on the x-axis at $\pm 1$, we find:

```
>>> from sympy import Line, Point, Eq, Tuple, cse
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y, m, b, t
>>> p1 = Point(-1, 0)
>>> p2 = Point(1, 0)
>>> l = Line((0, b), slope=m)
>>> p3 = l.arbitrary_point(t)
>>> yaxis = Line(Eq(x, 0))
>>> pt = l.perpendicular_line(p3).intersection(yaxis)[0]
>>> T = Tuple(*solve(p3.distance(pt)-pt.distance(p2), t))
>>> cse(T)
([(x0, m**2 + 1), (x1, b*x0), (x2, sqrt(x0*(b - m)*(b + m))), (x3, 1/(m*x0))], [
x3*(-x1 - x2), x3*(-x1 + x2)])
```

Some hand simplification allows the points that are equidistant to line and the two points (here, on the x-axis) to be written as

$$
a = m^2 + 1$$$$
s = \sqrt{a \cdot (b^2 - m^2)}$$$$
e = (0, b-(a \cdot b \pm s)/m^2)
$$

Since the argument of the square root cannot be negative, we must have $b^2 >= m^2$. This is equivalent to the condition $y_1y_2>=0$ given by @anatoly. Since we cannot divide by zero, $m \neq 0$. (If the line intersects the y-axis, it cannot be a vertical line in general or collinear with the y-axis in particular). In the case of $m=0$ we have a line intersecting the y-axis at $b$ and seek a point on the y-axis $(0, y)$ that is equidistant to $(0, b)$ and $(1, 0)$ or $(-1, 0)$.

```
>>> solve(Point(0,y).distance((0,b))-Point(0,y).distance((1,0)), y)
[(b**2 - 1)/(2*b)]
```

So when the slope of the line is the same as the slope of the line connecting the two points (a slope of 0 in the orientation being used) then there is a single solution located at
$$e = (0, (b^2 - 1)/(2b))$$
And here we notice a second degenerate case: when the line passes through the two points there is no solution.

Demonstration of solution: for $m=1$ and $b=2$ we have

```
>>> m = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> a = m**2 + 1
>>> s = sqrt(a*(b**2 - m**2))
>>> e1, e2 = [(0, b - (a*b+sng*s)/m**2) for sgn in (-1, 1)]
>>> e1,e2
((0, -2 + sqrt(6)), (0, -sqrt(6) - 2))
```

These points should be equidistant from the line and either of $(-1,0)$ or $(1,0)$:

```
>>> line = Line((0,b), slope=m)
>>> line.distance(e1).equals(Point(e1).distance((1,0)))
True
>>> line.distance(e2).equals(Point(e2).distance((1,0)))
True
```